# Object vs Filesystem vs Database

Tags: android, sqlite, filesystems

I'm feching large data lets say news feeds from server is it efficient to hold it memory in form of objects ??? or I should go with database approach or saved data in file system. I.just wnat to hold this data till app is running as everytime app restart i'm making server call again to fetch data.

Comment: If the data does not exeeds memory capacity (depends on android version and device vendor) there is no need to put it into DB of file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want data to be load every time then keep your data in objects. There is not need to  save your data in to File System or in SQLite.
In java objects store in heap and In android there is a generally heap size is 16MB to 48MB.